# getIntent is not working inside MainActivity. Getting weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, menuitem

I have one MainActivity and I have defined below code in onCreate() method. The intention is, when MainActivity gets extra String "EXIT" then show Toast message:

```
Intent current = getIntent();
if (current !=null && current.getStringExtra("EXIT") != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

This MainActivity starts another activity "DayOne" on some button press like:

```
public void processGo(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DayOne.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Now I am returning back from "DayOne" to MainActivity after putting extra string "EXIT". This I am doing inside onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
if(item.getTitle().equals("Exit")){
    Intent i = new Intent(DayOne.this,MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.putExtra("EXIT", "EXIT");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The issue is, when MainActivity is getting called from DayOne with extra string "EXIT"; I am not seeing the Toast message defined in MainActivity. What is missing or wrong here?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You mean your control doesn't flow into if statement that you defined in MainActivity?

Comment: u r rite @Appu. It is not going inside if

Comment: I just copy paste you code and its working. I can see toast.

Comment: @Sonusingh... Just write finish(); after the Toast. is it exiting the app?? It should right (as this is the main activity)? But it is not. Why so?

Comment: @ravitiwari did you try what I pinged you in SO room?

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for your help. I have figured out the issue. Please see my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your comments and helps.

I have figured out the issue here. It was because the manifest file had entry an entry  android:launchMode="singleInstance" for Both the activities (MainActivity and DayOne Activity)..

Removing it from there, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First check your `null` then get the `Intent String`, can you just make your code look like below within in onCreate of MainActivity@

```
Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();
if(extra!=null){

 String _StrExit=extra.getString("EXIT");

 if(_StrExit.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")){
 Toast.makeText(this, "exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
  }
```

**Update**
*Make change while calling Intent from menuitem*

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getTitle().equals("Exit")){
        Intent i = new Intent(DayOne.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        String _Str="EXIT";
        i.putExtra("EXIT", _Str);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Print log inside onCreate of MainActivity.!

Comment: no @Robin. This also dint work.. How does it make any difference by using _Str var or "EXIT" inside i.putExtra??

I also realized one thing that, "exit" var in MainActivity is setting as null !! I tried Toast just after if(extra != null){, it dint print either.. Whats happening here don't know !!

Comment: @ravitiwari post your code using pastie.org will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent current = getIntent();
    if (current != null && current.getStringExtra("EXIT") != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void processGo(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneDayActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

**OneDayActivity:**

```
public class OneDayActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_one);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.day_one, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Exit")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.putExtra("EXIT", "EXIT");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: did you try it inside 

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

function instead of onPrevious ?? Please check and then let me know what you see..

Comment: Yes its working with onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), I can see the Toast. Check the updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

dont clear the stack instead of if you want to do some task when you come back to your main activity (using "EXIT" string) you can achieve that using `onActivityResult` also.:

```
 public void processGo(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DayOne.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i,10); // 10 is the id to handle
    }



 @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
    {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        switch ( requestCode )
        {
            case ( 10 ): // id that we pass on start activity
            {
                if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK )
                {


                 Toast.makeText(this, "exiting"+data.getStringExtra( "EXIT", "" ),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }
            break;
       }
  }
```

On finish

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
if(item.getTitle().equals("Exit")){
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra( "EXIT", "EXIT" );
        setResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent );
        finish();
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

on finish it will go back to Main Activity and call `onActivityResult` automatically where you can do your task.

Sorry for the typo hope it will help.